# Parsing xml without root element

Tags: java, android, sax

folks! I've got an xml from server, which I tried to parse with Android SAX:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<News id="148364">
    <Title>Title</Title>
    <Desc>Desc</Desc>
    <Body>Body</Body>
    <Source_URL>example.url</Source_URL>
    <Source_Title>Title</Source_Title_Heb>
    <News_Date_Txt>20/06/11 18:14</News_Date_Txt>
    <News_Attachment>/Downloads/News_148364_1.htm</News_Attachment>
</News>
```

When I tried to do following:

```
RootElement root=new RootElement("News");
```

I received exception:

```
android.sax.BadXmlException: root element name does not match. Expected "News", Got "http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml:html"
```

What could it be? How do I get child nodes without root?

Comment: Have you tried printing out what you are parsing? It looks to me like you're not parsing the XML document you think you are...

Comment: In addition to citizen conn's comment, it seems the xml is coming embedded inside an html document or so. How does the server send the XML to you? Have a look again at what you are parsing.

Comment: Outside chance there's a namespace issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to configure your `SAXParser` to not use *XML Schema validation*

```
SAXParserFactory parser = SAXParserFactory.newInstance();
parser.setValidating(false);
parser.setNamespaceAware(false);
```